# Keep getting error trying to save a record in ms access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I kept getting an error with `Me.Dirty = False` or `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`.  With `Me.Dirty = False` it was 'invalid property', and with `docmd` it was error 2501.

After some experimenting I tried a `Me.Refresh` command before the save command, and the error stopped occurring.

I'm just sharing this in case anyone else gets a sticky save error (especially if it goes away after they press f5 in the debugger) - just put a `Me.Refresh` command before the save and it might help you out.

Also if anyone knows why a refresh before the save fixes it, I'd be interested.

**PS:** - History - after I noticed that if I pressed F5 in the debugger after I got the error, then the record actually did get saved on the retry with no further errors.

Then I tried putting a dialog box up for the user in an on error handler with a resume to retry the save, and after they clicked OK the record saved and the error did not recur.

That's how I guessed a refresh might help, since the dialog forced some kind of refresh.  It was a kind of wild guess, but it worked.

Comment: It's perfectly ok to share your knowledge, so thank you. But I suggest you post your question in a Q&A format, according to the way StackOverflow works.

Comment: ^ I would recommend deleting your current post and repost with something like "I was having an issue with `This` and fix it by doing `This` can someone explain why that solved the problem?"

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply assign `true` to `Me.Dirty`, because `Me.Dirty` is a read-only variable. The command `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` can only be executed if the Form is dirty. So what i always do is this:

```
If Me.Dirty Then
   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End If
```

If this answer doesn't help, you should post your code. So we can see other things that may lead to the error.

Comment: While it was a quite some time ago, I do recall that I had to write into my code saying If Me.Dirty then Me.Dirty = False.  For whatever reason I needed it to fix an issue, though it was a little too long ago for me to remember.  An example of this cane be found [here](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-01.html)